# How to scan db result into struct by field name

Tags: go

How to scan db results into struct by name?

```
type User struct {
    id          int
    client_id   int
    email       string
}

rows, _ := tx.Query(ctx, "SELECT id, client_id, email FROM main.user WHERE email=$1", "alias@example.com")
users, err := pgx.CollectRows(rows, pgx.RowToStructByName[User])
if err != nil {
fmt.Printf("CollectRows error: %v", err)
    return
}

for _, user := range users {
    fmt.Printf("%d: $%s\n", user.client_id, user.email)
}
```

Error

```
struct doesn't have corresponding row field id
```

Comment: You need to [export](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the identifiers. Make the fields' names start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `User`'s fields public and use `db` tag:

```
type User struct {
    ID          int     `db:"id"`
    ClientID    int     `db:"client_id"`
    Email       string  `db:"email"`
}
```